# Android in app billing v3 response not including orderId

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have spent almost two days working on in-app billing for Android. Everything works fine but at the end I am not getting `orderId` in the JSON response and this is freaking my mind out. I don’t know what I am missing. Any help is appreciated. This is the JSON response I get in `purchaseFinishListener`:

```
jsonPurchaseInfo: {"packageName":"com.app.mikedevice","productId":"monthly","purchaseTime":1429697010648,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"adbidjaciiidgknlglflebfb.AO-J1OxdrgGs2kFS-xf6Qo7j3eKabw4-Rto9xli4XqpPua_WtJVLNJSIpd3Oxwq7s_Uja4bVywEFf-iUP1g1dByizN984WHYi12ekQZ8T7X6oiitr5uiX2c","autoRenewing":true}
```

Comment: I noticed it too. There's this issue in the issue tracker  https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=205 Ideally Google Wallet Merchant Order Number should be returned as orderId field of the INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA JSON field (in V3) as per http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

Comment: The only reason I can think of is google not sending orderId for test purchases made by license-test users for app released to alpha/beta group as there is no resulting charges to the user meaning no order is created in the Google Wallet. But still I believe, a fake orderId should be returned just like how we get in static responses else it is difficult to perform an end-to-end purchase flow test.

Comment: @random let me know if you find any solution to this...

Comment: @random : thanks Sir,  for your kind efforts. Highly appreciated

Comment: 'orderId' is blank for sandbox purchases - https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#purchase-data-table

Answer (score 3):

You're probably using your Google account as tester - check it in Google Play dashboard.

Make sure on the device you are testing there is only one Google account which is not a tester (I created a new account).
It works for me.

- To test that this step is working try buying a consumable product you should see a Google dialog with a message saying this is a test purchase (or text similar).
  Once you delete the test account and log in with new one it should work.